# PrependText instead of AppendText?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the code below to write some text to a file. Instead of using AppendText, is there a way to prepend new data that gets written to the text file? So instead of the newest entry being written to the bottom, it would be written to the top of the text document.

```
Public filePath As String = "c:\path\log.txt"
Public w As StreamWriter

w = File.AppendText(filePath)
    w.WriteLine('Blah Blah')
    w.Flush()
    w.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With most common file systems, no.  You will have to copy the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could prepend it this way.

```
Dim txtList As New List(Of String)

txtList.Add("top line of text")

Using sr As New StreamReader("c:\path\log.txt")
  While Not sr.EndOfStream()     
    txtList.Add(sr.ReadLine)
  End While
End Using

Using sw As New StreamWriter("c:\path\log.txt")
  For Each line As String In txtList
    sw.WriteLine(line)
  Next
End Using
```